# JavaScript Date Validation RegEx OR JS?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, date, time

I'm using a date picker built in to my device and it returns the date in format YYYY/MM/DD
and returns the time in format HH:MM 24 hours.

The overall returned string is YYYY/MM/DDT/HH/MM
T being the separator.

What is the best way to validate this so that it matches the format YYYY/MM/DD/T/HH/MM
Regex ? Does JavaScript have validation for date/time built it even if i have to split at T so i have the date and time in separate variables?

Whats the best way/algorithm to do this aswell preformance wise?

If i split my varible in to array like...

["YYYY/MM/DD","HH:MM"]

Is there a regex or js function that validates this best? Preformance is key.

Thanks

Comment: *"Preformance (sic) is key."* Why?

Comment: Will be doing it on very low end devices  + 30/40 times

Comment: Fair enough. You wrote *"The overall returned string is YYYY/MM/DDT/HH/MM T being the separator."* But from what you say later, I'm guessing it's actually `YYYY/MM/DDTHH:MM`?

Comment: Validation should always be done on server side. Client side validation is optional, for UX purpose.

Comment: Yes will also be done at server side, but as the application is packaged in blackberry we are doing it here to so it can work offline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't be worried about performance, you're not going to be doing this hundreds of thousands of times in a tight loop, presumably.

A [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) is a good way to do it, and will be easy to write; if you create the regex once and reuse it, it should perform well too.

Assuming your example of the format is a typo and you meant `YYYY/MM/DDTHH:MM`, a modern JavaScript engine should also support using that string as the argument to `new Date(...)` provided you change the `/` to `-` (which you can readily do via `String#replace`). That's because it fits the [pared-down ISO-8601 format](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) defined as part of ES5. But older engines (IE8 and earlier, for instance) may not support it, you'd have to test on the browsers you intend to support. But if it's really `YYYY/MM/DDT/HH/MM`, ignore this paragraph.